# How to parse this Python list

Tags: python, list

Very new to Python, how can I parse this Python list with a `while` of `for` statement.

```py
weather = [
    ("Sunday", "zero", "Sunny"),
    ("Monday","one","Cloudy"),
    ("Tuesday", "two", "Windy"),
    ("Wednesday","three","Rainy"),
    ("Thursday", "four", "Partial Cloudy"),
    ("Friday","five","Full Sun"),
]
```

Thanks in advance!
Kevin

```py
for i in range(len(weather)):
  print(weather[i])
```

Only gives me the first letter of each group.

Comment: Your code gives me the correct output, can you provide your full code?

Comment: Your code returns the correct output, do you have a code before or after the for loop?

Also, your for loop can be modified to 
`for i in weather:
  print(i)`

Answer (score 3):

Using a while loop:

```
i = 0
while i < len(weather):
    day, number, condition = weather[i]
    print(day, number, condition)
    i += 1
```

Using a for loop:

```
for day, number, condition in weather:
    print(day, number, condition)
```

Both the `while` and `for` loops will iterate over the weather list and assign each element of the tuple to the respective variables day, number, and condition. Then, you can print these variables to display the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `join` before each weather[i]

```py
weather = [
    ("Sunday", "zero", "Sunny"),
    ("Monday","one","Cloudy"),
    ("Tuesday", "two", "Windy"),
    ("Wednesday","three","Rainy"),
    ("Thursday", "four", "Partial Cloudy"),
    ("Friday","five","Full Sun"),
]
for i in range(len(weather)):
  print(" ".join(weather[i]))
```